# For Loop with Array is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that adds one word to the `words` variable. When the array is at certain lengths I want an image's `src` to change depending on the array length. Can't seem to get it to work.

```
var words = [];

var str = words;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].length === 1) {
        img.src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"


        if (str[i].length === 2) {
            img.src = "http://placehold.it/200x150"

        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `words` is empty, and as such so is `str`, so there's nothing to loop over?

Comment: I have other code that fills the word var

Comment: Nesting `if(str[i].length === 2)` in `if(str[i].length === 1)` is useless.

Comment: (1) Missing semicolons after `img.src...."`. (2) Define "Can't seem to get it to work." What is the expected output as opposed to what you get? What errors are showing in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are verifying the length of the position, you need to verify the array directly:

```
if (words.length === 1) {
  img.src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"
} else if (words.length === 2) {
  img.src = "http://placehold.it/200x150"
}
```

for that case you don't need a loop

Comment: The array starts empty. 
Then things are added to it. 
The console.log shows that the word's length are 1 & 2 but the image is not updated?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to dynamically change the image at certain breakpoints, you will also have to register a callback on your button to determine if an update is needed.

```
var words = [];

$(button).click(function() {
  words.push("whatever");
  var img = // get img here

  if (words.length === 1) {
    img.src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
  } else if (words.length === 2) {
    img.src = "http://placehold.it/200x150";
  } 

  // etc
});
```

**Edit:** Here is a fiddle so you can see it working https://jsfiddle.net/4273v7c7/

Comment: The array starts empty. 
Then things are added to it. 
The console.log shows that the word's length are 1 & 2 but the image is not updated?

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi check the fiddle I linked. Let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for that.

```
var words = [];
var str = [0,"http://placehold.it/350x150", "http://placehold.it/200x150", ... ];
img.src = str[words.length] || img.src;
```

This will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

As Oriol commented, "Nesting `if(str[i].length === 2)` in `if(str[i].length === 1)`is useless."

It should be:

```
var words = [];

var str = words;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].length === 1) {
        img.src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
    }
    else if (str[i].length === 2) {
        img.src = "http://placehold.it/200x150";
    }
}
```

Comment: The array starts empty. 
Then things are added to it. 
The console.log shows that the word's length are 1 & 2 but the image is not updated?